# Is there a way to update JavaFX Border?

Tags: java, javafx, border

I have application with couple of color schemas, which can be switched dynamically. I would like to create JavaFX `Region`, set `Border` on it once, and then only change its color, without creating another object and set it - because then I also need to pass somehow width, and it doesn't change.

Currently I create and set border like that:

```
 Border border = new Border(
                   new BorderStroke(
                       borderColor, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, 
                     new BorderWidths(borderWidth)));
 this.setBorder(border);
```

**Is there a way to change only color of this border after creating it?**

I also thought about getting it somehow from current border, but it doesn't look very clear too:

```
region.getBorder().getStrokes().get(0).getWidths().getBottom();
```

and I still have to create new object and set it then.

Or maybe there is some better way to do it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the border programatically, I think the only solution is to create a new `Border`. Somethink like:

```
BorderStroke borderStroke = region.getBorder().getStrokes().get(0);

region.setBorder(null);
region.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(
        cp.getValue(), borderStroke.getTopStyle(), borderStroke.getRadii(),
        borderStroke.getWidths())));
```

But if you set the border from CSS, you can simply change only the color:

```
public class RegionBorder extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Region region = new Region();
        // Standard color, width, etc ...
        region.getStyleClass().add("myborderedregion");

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(region);

        ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker();
        // Change only the color
        cp.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> 
                region.setStyle("-fx-border-color: " + String.format( "#%02X%02X%02X",
                (int)( cp.getValue().getRed() * 255 ),
                (int)( cp.getValue().getGreen() * 255 ),
                (int)( cp.getValue().getBlue() * 255 ) )));

        bp.setBottom(cp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("app.css").toString());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*in app.css:*

```
.myborderedregion {
    -fx-border-color:green;
    -fx-border-width:5px
}
```